# Power func shows error when is put as a denominator in c

Tags: c, modulo

```
double length=3
double m=10
n= (n)% pow(m, length);
```

shows error when length is double, previously defined.
Code is compiled in visual studio 2013.

Comment: Define `shows error`, is it a compilation error? is it a runtime error, the result is unexpected? what is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Compilation..It says expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Answer (score 4):

I think, the error is in the usage of the `%` operator here. The return value of `pow()` is double, and you're not supposed to use `%` with an operand of type `double`.

Related reading: chapter  6.5.5, paragraph 2, `C99` standard

> The operands of the % operator shall have integer type.

To avoid, you can *cast* the return value of `pow()` to `int` before using as an operand of `%`.

Comment: or if `n` is `double`, use `fmod`

Answer (score 0):

pow() function return double type value . You have to cast the return type in integer because n is an integer and it can't store double type value .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  double length = 3, m = 10;
  int n = 36;
  n %= (int)pow(m,length);//Cast the return value because pow returns double but n is not .
  printf("%d\n",n);
  return 0;
}
```